# Extracting common date from a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a `column` that has multiple repetitive dates, and I would like to extract the common dates, how can I do this in `R` using `dplyr`?

Sample

```
1/1/2004
1/1/2004
1/1/2004 
1/2/2004
1/2/2004
2/3/2004
2/3/2004
3/4/2004
3/4/2004
```

Desired output

```
1/1/2004
1/2/2004
2/3/2004
3/4/2004
```

Comment: You can use `distinct` from `library(dplyr)`. `df %>% distinct(V1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `summarise`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dates <- tibble(
  dates = c("2004/01/01", 
            "2004/01/01", 
            "2004/01/01", 
            "2004/01/01",
            "2004/01/02",
            "2004/01/03",
            "2004/01/04")
)

dates %>% 
  mutate(dates = lubridate::ymd(dates)) %>% 
  group_by(dates) %>% 
  summarise(dates = max(dates))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   dates     
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2004-01-01
#> 2 2004-01-02
#> 3 2004-01-03
#> 4 2004-01-04
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>